# Transistor as switch that can handle a high base current

Tags: transistors, specifications, base

Which cheap, simple transistor can handle a high base current and doesn't need a base resistor to use it as switch?

Comment: Is there a reason why a simple series resistor on the base (or a MOSFET, which has no base current and can be driven without a resistor in many cases) is unsuitable for your application?

Comment: A BJT that you can use with no base resistor? Such a thing doesn't exist.  There may be some that have a base resistor built into the same package, though.

Comment: What do you mean by Q, by the way?

Comment: 2N3055 (from On Semi)  can have 7A base current but you may still need a resistor

Comment: `high base current` how high? What's the actual application? Why do you need specifically a "high-base-current-capable" transistor? There are digital transistors that come with internal resistors. So they don't require any extra base and base-emitter resistors to be used as a switch. Do you mean one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that - as a precondition for switching applications (saturation) - the potential at the collector must be smaller than the base potential (npn case). That means: Both pn junctions are forward biased - the B-E junction as well as the B-C junction (due to a large voltage drop across the collector resistor Rc).

As a result, the current into the base consists of two portions and, hence, is much larger than anticipated by the relation Ib=Ic/B (for linear applications).

Therefore, it is not really necessary to have a resistor Rb between the switching voltage Vs and the base node - as long as this voltage Vs has the "correct" value to drive the BJT into saturation (Vs in the region 0.65...0.75 volts). But - how can we be sure about this "correct" Vbe value?

But in practical applications, the switching voltage Vs has a value of several volts (typical value Vs=5 volts). As a consquence, we need such a resistor Rs with a value of **Rs=(Vs-Vbe)/Ib**.

It is common practice to implement some margin into this calculation by using Vbe=0.7 volts (or a similar value) and for Ib approximately 10% of the required Ic value.

Comment: *"potential at the collector"* -- meaning Vce vs. Vbe? This seems contrary to experience. Are you describing saturation conditions? Note that Vce(sat) isn't necessarily very close to zero, indeed it can be higher than Vbe(sat).  Usually we aren't concerned with beta (B = capital or "large signal" beta?), but saturation gives a "forced hFE" which is designed for reliable saturated operation over load, manufacturing, and temperature ranges.

Comment: Yes - as I have mentioned: Both pn junctions are forward biased - and this is the definition for saturation (precondition for switching applications). What do you mean with "forced hfe"? At first, hfe is a small signal parameter (linear applications) and, secondly, the base current is simply the result of the two forward biased pn junctions. So I would not consider the base current as a "forced" quantity.

Comment: Does that mean high-voltage types (with "Vce(sat)" over 3V) don't actually saturate?  Notice I wrote "hFE", the large-signal version: this is simply instantaneous Ic/Ib. It differs from the small signal figure, at modest Vce, with h_fe = d(Ic) / d(Ib).

Comment: "Does that mean..." - what do you mean with "THAT" ? I did nothing else than to mention/explain the definition for saturation (example npn-transistor).  Anything wrong with "that" ? More than that, I never have mention any value for Vce. I only spoke about the potentials at the collector node in comparison to the potential at the base node. And the difference of both is Vcb (and not Vce).